# Any way I press Ctrl V in a folder and image taken via PrtScr is saved as a new image file rather first copying it to mspaint?

Tags: images, shortcuts, copy-paste

I take a snapshot of my desktop by pressing PrintScreen button on keyboard. Then I want to make a new image file of it when I press Ctrl V in any of my folder rather than first copying it on a image editing program (like mspaint).

Is there any way out for this? As I do this many times, I need some fast way for it.

Please suggest..

Comment: If you're on Windows 8, Win Key + Printscreen saves it to the Screenshots folder in your Pictures library

Answer (score 1):

If you use [**Greenshot**](http://getgreenshot.org), it can be configured to auto-save in your chosen screenshots directory:

[image: 2]

If you absolutely *must* use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for some reason, one possible solution could be to select the "Copy file path to clipboard..." option shown above, and select your Temp (Temporary Files) folder to be the default save location. Then every time you take a screenshot, Greenshot will auto-save to the Temp folder, and immediately afterwards you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy the image anywhere you please. If you want, you can periodically delete all auto-saved screenshots from your Temp folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use some tool for it:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screen-shots

This aint copy-paste, but you can select an area and save it as a file directly

Comment: This is not my question. I am aware of snipping tool, but we need to manually click on the save button and provide a file name and path to save the image file. I need to automate this process, so that clicking Ctrl V automatically creates a file with that image.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools, that can help you with this. My favorite is [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/) (it can hook into the print screen key, but also offers a window to select an area if you want), but if you google for "screen capture utility" you will find loads of others.